# spring application doesn't quit

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code:

```
public class TutorialSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rabbit-sender-context.xml");//loading beans
        AmqpTemplate aTemplate = (AmqpTemplate) context.getBean("tutorialTemplate");// getting a reference to the sender bean
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("messageType", "ETL:ToFile");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            aTemplate.convertAndSend("ETLQueue",obj.toString());// send
          //  aTemplate.convertAndSend("Message # " + i + " on " + new Date());// send
        }

        System.out.println("send is done");
    }

}
```

Then I run the app, it runs to the last line and I could see "Send is done" is printed, but the app doesn't exit. Is it because of spring prevent it to quit? how can I quit?

update: we can't use `context.close()` directly since there is so close() function, instead need to use the following

```
 ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
```

Comment: Instead of casting, just use a more specific type for your `context` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring application context stays open, and so even though your main thread is over, other threads are still available and runnable. Close out the context with `context.close()` to shut things down cleanly.

Additionally, consider using Spring Boot for future programs. You'd still need to actively close the context to terminate the program automatically, but the setup is a good bit easier.

Answer (score -2):

It's likely that Spring has some threads running which haven't closed by the time your `main` method is done. Calling `System.exit(0)` will exit the program.

Comment: Using `System.exit` is a very blunt instrument and no substitute for understanding what's happening